# Why does the object id change following failed validations in a rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've generated a simple rails app using scaffolding. In the user model I have added a validation for the presence of name. I am using debug(@user.object_id) and showing at the top of my user edit page in edit.html.erb

I've purposefully left the name blank and tried to submit the form. The usual errors are rendered but every time I submit the form, the @user's object id changes. Could someone please explain why the object_id is changing? My assumption was that the @user is still the same object (since we're in the same page, just adding errors and re-rendering the edit.html.erb on failed update)

Comment: You've been a member for 7 years, but just asked your first question today?!?  Fascinating!  Can you include the code that's causing the problem?  Ideally we should see any code in the affected codepath, less the code that you've verified isn't causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably confused by the fact, that `render :edit` in the `update` method just renders the `edit` template, but doesn't redirect to the `edit` page - that's right.

But, actually this is what happens in your scenario:

- `edit` page is visited, `@user` assigned in the `edit` method of `UsersController`
- form is submitted, `update` action is called and found `@user` is assigned in the `update` method and renders `edit` template

Thus, on submitting a form different method is called and the state changes

Comment: Thank you for the step by step explanation

Answer (score 1):

No, your assumption is not correct. HTTP calls are stateless, meaning that state does not persist between calls (i.e. every call is independent of each other). Every time your form is submitted, a new object is created and assigned to the variable `@user`. Since a new (and different) object is created during each call, their `object_id`s will be different.